# java.lang.NullPointerException in netbeans

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

i'm writing a bit of code and i keep getting this error, it's to do with where i call network.addstation

here's the code, there are other methods in the network method but i thought i'd just show one, but it appears when you call any method. any help would be much appreaciated. thanks.

```
public class MyNetworkReader implements NetworkReader {

    Network network = null;

    @Override
    public Network read(InputStream stream) {
        Scanner scan = null;
        scan = new Scanner(stream);
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            String fromStation = scan.next();
            if (!fromStation.equalsIgnoreCase("connection:")) ;
            network.addStation(fromStation)
            System.out.println(fromStation);
        }
    }

    return network;
}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class MyNetwork implements Network {


    HashMap<String, ArrayList> stations = new HashMap<String, ArrayList>();


    public void addStation(String station) {
        stations.put(station, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you constructing a MyNetwork instance anywhere?

Seems like you want

```
 Network network = null;
```

To be

```
MyNetwork network = new MyNetwork();
```

Because you're trying to call a method on an uninitiated object. But your MyNetwork class needs a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Note you can also get this error immediately upon running C++ code, with the default NetBeans setup, if your Project's Properties->Run->Console Type is set to Internal Terminal and not External Terminal; at least when using FLTK graphics on Ubuntu.  In this case it's a NetBeans internal handshaking problem and not a source code problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're yourself initializing network to null, in second line of your code, then it will obviously throw NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

As DragonLord said, it is not a source code issue. You will be able to tell because that should happen whenever you run any C++ code. I had the same problem. I did something slightly different than DragonLord, though. I set the output of the program to Project Properties>Run>Console Type and set it to Standard Output.